# How to instantly redirect the user to a new page via router when the user logs in succesfully(password, username are correct)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Via vue.js I've made a login form with a username and password, and set conditions for them. When the user submits the correct username and password I want to redirect them to a new page vie the vue.js Router. So for example if the user is currently located in "localhost8080/", after a successful login I want to immediately send them to "localhost8080/#/profile"

```
                validate() {
                var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                var atSign = email.indexOf("@");

                var error = document.getElementById("error");
                var mistakes = "";
                var hasErrors = false;

                if (this.newP != this.password){
                    mistakes += "Entered password is incorrect. ";
                    hasErrors = true;
                }

                if (atSign === -1) {
                    mistakes += "The email is missing an '@' sign.";
                    hasErrors = true;
                }
                // console.log(this.newP.length)
                if (hasErrors === true) {
                    error.innerHTML = mistakes;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    alert("Login confirmed");
                    return true;
                //I realize it's supposed to be here, but I do not know                                                                
                //how to write it.
                }
                }
```

Comment: If you're using a SPA (single-page application), you can modify the URL hash. If it's multi-page, simply setup an endpoint for the page and change the URL provided on the window object.

Comment: Check out this: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You using vue-router, better to use programmatic navigation.

Link: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

```
if(loginConfirmed) {
    this.$router.push({ path: 'dashboard' });
}
```